# What format does this plugin require the callback string to be in? (jquery-ui-multisearch)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm using a plugin called "Jquery-ui-multisearch" which offers an autocomplete in an input element based on either an array you provide or an external source (ajax/api/etc). Found here: http://bseth99.github.io/jquery-ui-multisearch/index.html

I'm currently attempting to use the plugin to provide an autocomplete suggestion based on an array of strings returned from an ajax database call, but I can't figure out what format the plugin wants to see this in.

Here is the example initalization of the plugin.

```
$(function() {
   $("#myMultiSearch").multisearch({
      source: function ( term, callback ) { ... } //A function can implement a data search and should call the passed in callback with the results.
   });
});
```

And here's what my code looks like:

```
$("#search").multisearch({
  source: function (term, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: postUrl,
            data: {searchterm:term},
        })
        .done(function(data) { //data == ["abc","abcd","abcde"]; 
            callback(data); 
        });
  });
```

Looks similar to what they do here: http://bseth99.github.io/jquery-ui-multisearch/examples/movies.html - which looks like this:

```
source: function( term, callback ) {
         movies.search( term ).done( function() { callback( movies.toJSON() ); } );
      },
```

I have also tried callback(data.toJSON()); or changing the output data to things like {"abc","abcd","abcde"}  or ("abc","abcd","abcde") etc. etc. All result in either undefined results or a box coming up with no results at all.

So how do I pass the returned array of items to the multisearch function so that it can display it in the results?

Please let me know if I need to communicate anything more specifically - I know it's hard to diagnose problems especially on third party plugins when the asker isn't very clear.

Comment: So you've tried just passing a string of JSON back, something like  `callback('{"test":"test", "test2":"test2"}');` etc

Comment: try putting a `console.log(data);` inside the `done` function - see what gets output

Comment: @adeneo Adding `callback('{"name":"test", "name":"test2"}');` will trigger a dropdown of 6 items that are all undefined. 
@allicam - what gets returned back from the ajax call isn't too much of an issue because I can return whatever I want. For the purposes of debugging I'm just creating my own string and using that as an argument in callback().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had posted this as an issue on github last month and the writer got back to me here: https://github.com/bseth99/jquery-ui-multisearch/issues/2

I had to take the array from php and create a new array of hashes from it. Here's my code.

```
.done(function(data) {
        var jsonparse = JSON.parse(data);
        var hashArray = [];
        jsonparse.forEach(function(entry) {
            hashArray.unshift({name: entry});
        });
        //console.log(hashArray);

        callback(hashArray); //Same format as the line below.

        //callback([{ name: "item1" },{ name: "item2" }]); //This works.

})
```

Thanks for your help guys!